# How to compare key/value dictionary with == operator on a IReadOnlyCollection<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have a `MultiValueDictionary<string, string>` where I am trying to get a key by value.

```
var dic = na.prevNext; // Getter to get MultiValueDictionary

string nodePointingToThisOne = "";
foreach (var item in dic)
{
    if(item.Value == "test")
    {
        nodePointingToThisOne = item.Key;
    }
    break;
}
```

This does not work so I tried Linq:

```
string nodePointingToThisOne = dic.Where(x => x.Value == this.nodeID).Select(x => x.Key);
```

But on both I get this error: `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<string>' and 'string'`

So my question is how do I make this comparison work for a read-only collection? I am aware that I get problems if a key exists multiple times but I reduced the problem to this one for now.

I read 
[Get Dictionary key by using the dictionary value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001908/get-dictionary-key-by-using-the-dictionary-value)

[LINQ: Getting Keys for a given list of Values from Dictionary and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497592/linq-getting-keys-for-a-given-list-of-values-from-dictionary-and-vice-versa)

[get dictionary key by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444033/get-dictionary-key-by-value)

[Getting key of value of a generic Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255341/getting-key-of-value-of-a-generic-dictionary)

[Get key from value - Dictionary<string, List<string>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860643/get-key-from-value-dictionarystring-liststring)

but they deal with a "normal" dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Value` property it self may contain multiple values you can't compare it directly against certain string using `==` operator. Use `Contains()` instead :

```
.....
if (item.Value.Contains("test"))
{
    .....
}
```

...or in method chain version :

```
string nodePointingToThisOne = dic.Where(x => x.Value.Contains("test"))
                                  .Select(x => x.Key)
                                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to iterate by Keys and then compare the value, and return the Key only if the Value matches.

Like this:

```
foreach (var key in dic.Keys)
{
    if(dic[key].Contains("your value"))
        return key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over keys like this

```
   foreach (var key in dic.Keys)
    {
        if(key == "your key")
            return key;
    }
```

You can also iterate over values like this

```
    foreach (var v in dic.Values)
    {
        if(v == "your value")
            return v;
    }
```

**Example:**

```
        Dictionary<string, string> c = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        c.Add("Pk", "Pakistan");
        c.Add("Aus", "Australia");
        c.Add("Ind", "India");
        c.Add("Nz", "New Zeland");
        c.Add("SA", "South Africa");

        foreach (var v in c.Values)
        {
            if (v == "Australia")
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Your Value is = " + v);
                // perform your task 
            }
        }

        foreach (var k in c.Keys)
        {
            if (k == "Aus")
            {
                // perform your task    
                Console.WriteLine("Your Key is = " + k);
            }
        }
```

**Output:**

Your Value is = "Australia" 
Your Key is = "Aus"

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [MultiValueDictionary,](https://gist.github.com/njonsson/338938) line 81 will give you a hint. It is:

```
 [TestInitialize]
 public void TestInitialize()
 {
     MultiValueDictionary = new MultiValueDictionary<TestKey, string>();
 }

 protected static void AssertAreEqual( IDictionary<TestKey, string[]> expected,
 IMultiValueDictionary<TestKey, string> actual )
 {
     Assert.AreEqual( expected.Count, actual.Count );
     foreach ( var k in expected.Keys )
     {
         var expectedValues = expected[ k ];
         var actualValues = actual[ k ];
         AssertAreEqual( expectedValues, actualValues );
     }
 }
```

So for your case, the solution is similar:

```
foreach (var item in dic.keys)
{
    if(dict[item] == "test")
    {
        nodePointingToThisOne = item;
        return nodePointingToThisOne;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

worked for me:

```
foreach (int i in Dictionary.Keys)
{
   if (Dictionary.Values.ToString() == "Your Value")
   {
      return Dictionary.Keys;
   }
}
```